# Inheritance set-up

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm working on creating a deck of cards as a class, and I think I have messed up the inheritance.

```
import random as rand


class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value, color, whole):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
        self.color = color
        self.whole = whole

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"The suit is {self.suit}, the value is {self.value}, the color is {self.color}"


class Deck(Card):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.suit, self.value, self.color, self.whole)
        self.cards = None

    def build(self):
        suits = ["Diamonds, Clubs, Hearts, Spades"]
        values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
        color = ["Red", "Black"]
        self.cards = [suits, values, color]
        return self.cards


class Game(Card):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.suit, self.value, self.color, self.whole)

    def draw_cards(self):
        w1, w2, w3 = None, None, None
        n1 = rand.randint(1, 4)
        n2 = rand.randint(1, 13)
        n3 = rand.randint(1, 2)
        for i in range(self.suit):
            if i == n1:
                w1 = self.suit[i]
        for i in range(self.value):
            if i == n2:
                w2 = self.suit[i]
        for i in range(self.color):
            if i == n3:
                w3 = self.suit[i]
        self.whole = [w1, w2, w3]
        return self.whole
```

Can't seem the values of the objects to come from the superclass to the subclasses.

Comment: I think where you messed up is at the part where you started to use inheritance. It doesn't really make sense here. A deck is not a card, and a game is not a card.

Comment: Inheritance is a special link.
You can think of it like this : a class inherits from a parent class if you can say "it is a kind of".
Example : a Car is a kind of Vehicule.
It is a specialization of a vehicle.
A car and a vehicle share some attributes (both have a color, an engine, tyres) and some behavior.
A deck is composed of cards. A deck is not a kind of Card.
When you code `self.cards = None` you simply act that a deck is composed of cards.
This is not inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these should be subclasses of `Card`. A deck is a *collection* of cards:

```
from itertools import product
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
        if suit in ["Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            self.color = "Red"
        else:
            self.color = "Black"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"The suit is {self.suit}, the value is {self.value}, the color is {self.color}"

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
         suits = ["Diamonds, Clubs, Hearts, Spades"]
         values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
         self.cards = [Card(s, v) for s, v in product(suits, values)]

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def draw_card(self):
        c = self.cards.pop()
        return c
```

The `Deck` class wraps a list of pre-constructed cards, as well as providing methods like `shuffle` and `draw_card`.

Likewise, a game *uses* a deck of cards.

```
class Game(Card):
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = Deck()
        self.deck.shuffle()

    def draw_cards(self):
        return [self.deck.draw_card() for _ in range(3)]
```